Angular does not show new Images or Files after ng serve in Version 17 18
when creating a new angular app in Version 17,18 and start the server with ng serve, then new files in the assets folder will be shown with CANNOT GET..
when stopping the server and run ng serve again, then the files will be there.
for reproduction:
new app with:
ng new a17_test_image
then
ng serve
i tested it several times and with different versions. it worked with version 16 and from 17,18 it fails.
i also uninstalled angular and also node.js and re-installed it from the roots.
so the versions 17+18 do not work, if a service uploads files or add files like in a blogger app.
screenshot here


UPDATE:
You are adding in runtime, instead store the image as a base64 string in an angular property and render it using [src] that is the root cause.
Public assets folder cannot be updated programatically.

Make sure you have the assets folder added to the assets array in angular.json. When creating a new project in newer versions, the mapping may not be included by default, so we need to add it manually.
...
"assets": ["public"],
...


yes it is there.. and when stopping the server and restarting it, then the images are shown as used
in v17: localhost:4200/assets/test1.jpg

@RaimundPopp Could you try deleting .angular folder and running ng serve

yes, but still the same.
*i added the screenshot to the question

@RaimundPopp You are adding in runtime, instead store the image as a base64 string in an angular property and render it using [src] that is the root cause.

@RaimundPopp upload the files to a s3 bucket  or some file upload service or node.js backend and return the URL to the frontend instead
